# Switched outlet to light switch

Tags: electrical, switch, light

I have a switch that controls an outlet on the far side of the room. The outlet is behind our headboard and unused, so if possible, I don’t need to to access it. But I would like to use the switch location to control recessed lights. I have installed lights and run 14/2 into the switch box. Already in the switch box was ungrounded 2 wire and ungrounded 3-wire to control the outlet. The whites were connected and the blacks connected with a pigtail to the switch, and the third (red) wire to the switch as well.
What are the connections I need to make to the new dimmer switch switch to power the lights? (Sorry I don’t have any good pictures)

Comment: Key information: Open up the switched receptacle and report: What wires are connected on which screws *and* whether there is a tab connecting upper and lower screw on each side. The results of that will determine what to do next, because you can't have a dimmer on a receptacle.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking you mean to say there are black wires connected and pigtailed to the "OUTLET"  and a red to the outlet as well.
In that case the red should be the switched hot. That goes to your new lights.
Remember that if you remove the red wire 1/2 of the outlet will be dead.  To restore power you will need to wire a new bridge from black to screw that the red was on.

Answer (score 0):

The key question is what is the status of the receptacle. You generally don't want the receptacle switched once you have switched lights, and in fact you are not allowed to have it switched with a dimmer, because that could be damaging to non-light loads.

Also a bit of a concern about *ungrounded* existing cables. If allowed at the time of original installation, that is OK, but take a careful look - it may turn out that you actually have ground wires, combined with metal boxes, with the ground wire connected *outside* the box instead of inside.

Since you are using 14/2, you need to make sure this circuit is a 15A circuit. A 20A circuit must have 12 AWG wire throughout the circuit. If it is a 20A circuit, you need to either change it to 15A or replace the 14/2 with 12/2.

On to the wiring.

##### In the switch box:

- Incoming 2-wire black/white = hot/neutral.
- New 2-wire black/white to fixture = switched hot/neutral. Mark the black wire with a piece of red tape (not required by code, but helpful for organization, and from now on we'll call it "red").
- Existing 3-wire black/red/white = hot/switched hot/neutral.

Connections:

- All blacks together with a wire nut and use a pigtail (another short piece of black wire) to connect to the "hot" or "line" screw on the new switch.
- All whites together with a wire nut.
- New red to "switched hot" or "load" screw on the new switch.
- Cap the old red wire with a wire nut and use a piece of electrical tape to make sure it is secure.

##### In the receptacle box:

Check for a tab connecting both screws on each side. Almost certainly there will be one in place on the neutral (white) side. There may or may not be one in place on the hot (black and/or red) side.

- White to both neutral screws. If there is a tab in place, you only need to connect it to one screw. Which almost definitely means "white already in place, nothing to do".
- Remove the red wire and cap it with a wire nut and a piece of electrical tape.
- Black to both hot screws. If there is a tab in place (which is likely the case if only the red wire was connected before) then connect it to one screw and you are done. If there is no tab in place (which is likely the case if both the red and black wires were connected before) then connect two short pieces of black wire to the black wire from the cable and connect one to each screw.

Comment: Wow thanks manassehkatz. It is a 15a circuit and the existing wiring is ungrounded. I removed the old meta box and installed a 20cu. PVC receptacle in its place, to house the fat Lutron dimmer. I’ll be converting the outlet to “always hot.” I’ll follow your instructions and report back. Thanks again!

Comment: I highly recommend metal boxes, but plastic is legal, and it is very common to have to replace the original boxes to put in new stuff.

Comment: Do I NEED  to do anything in the receptacle box at this time to make the lights and other receptacles work? As I said I don’t need the outlet to be functioning other than carrying power through the circuit.

Comment: **Yes**. The catch is that code almost certainly requires the receptacle (basically one every 12', so effectively usually means one on each wall of a bedroom) and you *can't* leave it switched because you can't put a receptacle on a dimmer switch. But should be very easy to take care of that part - do *not* need a new receptacle or new box, likely just moving/changing one or two wires.

Comment: If you can't make use of the existing receptacle because it is too low (very common), you can probably run a 14/2 cable from that up to a new box positioned to be accessible, and use that for phone chargers or whatever else you need.

Comment: It’s more just that it’s buried behind our headboard and very heavy bed/mattress and I would rather not address reconfiguring the receptacle at this time if I can avoid it. Unless it must be done for the circuit to work…

Comment: @J.Johnson If it is currently 100% switched then there is an easy "don't have to open that box" fix. If it is currently 50% switched (top receptacle always on, bottom switched, or vice versa) then it really should be redone properly.

Comment: Thanks so much manassehkatz, you the man! Lights are up and running. I have another post in here for a similar situation but with a different configuration, perhaps you can take a look at that one for me when you have some time? I’ll send a link below.

Comment: Looks like you e already responded to my other post so I’ll circle back to that and work on it. Thanks so much for contributing as you do to this site, hugely helpful